# sequence prediction using lstm tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, prediction

so I am new to using Tensorflow so please bear with me.

I want to create a LSTM rnn for sequence prediction, but since i am also going to use this for tuning hyper parameters, i would like the input to be of the format 
[n1,n2,n3...] 
and output will be a single number.

eg: input[1,2,3,4] | output=[5]

I have created a dictionary like so:
dict = { "n1":array(1,2,3,4,5), "n2":array(2,3,4,5,6), "n3":array(3,4,5,6,7), "n4":array(4,5,6,7,8) }

labels/output=[5,6,7,8,9]

I would like to use an estimator, i was going to use DynamicRnnEstimator() but it is going to be removed in a future version and so i would like to create my own custom estimator for this.

i want to know how to create y own custom estimator for this particular scenario of training the mode to predict the next number given a sequence of "sequence_length".

i have many sequences for the training.

the code I have written till now is below:

```
# START

# IMPORTS

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import csv
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DynamicRnnEstimator
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
sequence_length = 4 # predict the 5th number give the previous sequence_length numbers.
batch_size = 10
n_epochs = 100
n_neurons = 5

# NORMALIZING THE DATA
def normalize_data(train, test):
    m11 = float(max(train))
    m12 = float(min(train))
    normalized_train = [float((x-m12)/(m11-m12)) for x in train]
    m21 = float(max(test))
    m22 = float(min(train))
    normalized_test = [float((x-m22)/(m21-m22)) for x in test]
    return normalized_train, normalized_test

# LOADING THE DATA
def load_data(train, test):
    with open(train, 'r') as csvfile1:
        reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter = ',')
        train = [ float(row[1]) for row in reader1]
    with open(test, 'r') as csvfile2:
        reader2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter = ',')
        test = [ float(row[1]) for row in reader2]
    normalized_train, normalized_test = normalize_data(train, test)
    global sequence_length
    trainx = [ normalized_train[i:i+sequence_length] for i in range(len(normalized_train) - sequence_length-2)]
    testx = [ normalized_test[i:i+sequence_length] for i in range(len(normalized_test) - sequence_length-2)]
    trainy = [ normalized_train[i] for i in range(sequence_length+1, len(normalized_train))]
    testy = [ normalized_test[i] for i in range(sequence_length+1, len(normalized_test))]
    return trainx, testx, trainy, testy

# Create Dict function
def create_dict(x,y):
    feature_dict = dict()
    global sequence_length
    for i in range(sequence_length):
        temp = "number"+str(i+1)
        feature_dict[temp] = x[:,i]
    labels = y
    return feature_dict, labels

# Training input function
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(100).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    # Return the read end of the pipeline.
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

# Create feature columns
def create_feature_columns():
    feature_column = []
    for i in range(sequence_length):
        feature_column.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="number"+str(i+1)))
    return feature_column

# Model_ function
def my_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
     net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
     for units in params['hidden_units']:
        net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
     logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=None)

def main():
    global sequence_length, batch_size, n_epochs, n_neurons
    trainx, testx, trainy, testy = load_data("train.csv", "test.csv")
    trainx, testx, trainy, testy = np.array(trainx), np.array(testx), np.array(trainy), np.array(testy )
    n_train = len(trainx)
    n_test = len(testx)
    feature_dict_train, label_train = create_dict(trainx, trainy)
    feature_dict_test, label_test = create_dict(testx, testy)
    feature_column = create_feature_columns()



main()
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Your current questions reads like "please finish my code". SO generally asks for concrete, specific questions. As a broad answer, try following the tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators. The only real difference should be your `model_fn` where you create your RNN cell and unroll it (e.g. using `dynamic_rnn`). You can also look at the `model_fn` https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d0f5bc17560fc97bcc7de9164aa3b237a8d5221d/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dynamic_rnn_estimator.py#L384. It should be easy once you remove most options.

Comment: okay got it, so just define my model_fn tocreate the lstm rnn using the dynamic_rnn() then decide what to do based on what the mode is? is that fine?

Comment: That is the high-level idea. The `DynamicRnnEstimator` is being deprecated because one can effectively achieve the same functionality by a custom `model_fn`. You can also just take the code of  `DynamicRnnEstimator`, remove all the options you don't need and refactor it do all the work in `model_fn`.